# Элемент WebBrowser

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Скажите, вот когда я использовал компонент Web Browser, то заметил, что он копия IE. Реально ли заменить двиг. IE, например, на двиг. FireFox? А то сайты коряво отображает, неудобно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот [**этот**](http://code.google.com/p/geckofx/) (GeckoFX) компонент использует движок от Firefox.

Или [**этот**](http://se7en-soft.com/moznet/getmoznet.aspx) (MozNET), правда он посложнее.